# Configuring gate driver for high side power switch

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm in the process of selecting a gate driver for n-channel MOSFETs to be used as high-side power switches. I stumbled upon some gate drivers with some specifications that I couldn't wrap my head around. I will use the [MIC5018YM4-TR](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5018.pdf) as an example.

Here is where I get confused. Under typical applications, it states that it can be used as a low-side power switch with the load voltage being limited only by the FET Vgs. However in the high-side image, it has the load voltage (5V) in this case tied to the Vs.

Is it possible to separate the FET drain from VS in this case? What I am trying to achieve is to run 12/24V on the drain side of the FET and supply VS separately through a different, non-isolated input of 3.3V. I can't think of any reason why I wouldn't be able to do this. I have linked the schematics below for clarity. Apologies if the answer is simple, I'm still learning. TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 9V part isn't going to work with 24v or even 12V

It's not possible to separate vs from the drain.

When switching N channel high side the gate voltage needs to go from near 0V (off) to more than the drain voltage (on)

Often, inexpensive parts are also less capable.